# Google Nexus, app not downloading from play store and Fragment showing empty after navigation

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, fragment, nexus-5

My app consisting of Tabs with fragments. If I navigate to other activity and come back the fragment is empty (this is happening only in nexus phone). In other android phones its working fine. Kindly help me out.